# Happy and you know it line continuing

Tags: java

I am trying to code "if you are happy and you know it in netbeans, but "then your face will surely show it is repeated 3 times and I only need it to show up one time. I can not figure out how to only have it show up one time

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ifYoureHappyVerse("clap your hands", "(clap clap)");
    ifYoureHappyVerse("clap your hands", "(clap clap)");
    ifYoureHappyVerse("clap your hands", "(clap clap)");
}


public static void ifYoureHappyVerse(String action, String sound) {
    System.out.println("If you're happy and you know it, " + action + sound
   +"\nIf you're happy and you know it, then your face will surely show it")
}
```

This is my code so far

Comment: Put the "face" part into a separate `System.out.println` and put it in your `main` after the three calls to `ifYourHappyVerse`.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing this line in a method that you are calling three times. Therefore it is printed three times. Extract the line that you want to print only once and encapsulate it in it's own method (maybe a bit too much in this trivial example) or just print it separately:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ifYoureHappyVerse("clap your hands", "(clap clap)");
    ifYoureHappyVerse("clap your hands", "(clap clap)");
    ifYoureHappyVerse("clap your hands", "(clap clap)");
    System.out.println("If you're happy and you know it, then your face will surely show it");
}


public static void ifYoureHappyVerse(String action, String sound) {
    System.out.println("If you're happy and you know it, " + action + sound)
}
```

Another idea could be to pass a boolean as a third parameter to the method that you are using as a flag if the sentence should be printed or not.

Comment: Yet another idea would be to have the tripple-printing *inside* `ifYoureHappyVerse` and only call it once, then one can also have the final sentence in there.